# how to check if class instances are instanceof another class

Tags: php

In php, it seems that a class is not a subclass of itself

```
php > var_dump(is_subclass_of('Exception', 'Exception'));
bool(false)
php > var_dump(is_subclass_of('ErrorException', 'Exception'));
bool(true)
```

However, instances of Exception and ErrorException are both instances of Exception, and that is the property I want to check for. Is there a function I could replace `is_subclass_of` with that would make the output be `true` for both expressions?

Comment: `class is not a subclass of itself` And why should it be?

Comment: How about using OR? If it is this class OR a subclass...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php

Comment: @u_mulder I never said it should be... if you read my question I want a function that returns true because instances of Exception are instances of Exception, and instances of ErrorException are instances of ErrorException

Comment: @rjdown that function requires its first argument to be an object, not a class name

Answer (score 1):

Define your own function that checks whether they're the same class name or one is a subclass of the other.

```
function same_or_subclass_of($class, $parent) {
    return $class == $parent || is_subclass_of($class, $parent);
}
```